# Should I save my "mission points" for anything in particular in Super Mario Run?

Tags: super-mario-run

You earn mission points (seen after clicking the *My Nintendo* button) by completing various achievements in the game. The only thing you cannot do with *mission points* is unlock Toad (which is done by linking your Nintendo account).

Is there anything I should be saving these points for?
Are Toad Rally Tickets going to be harder to come by later?
Is there a cost/benefit ratio for spending *mission points*?

Answer (score 1):

If you buy the game, you will get more Toad rally tickets. (I have a Nintendo Account, and have linked it, so I have Toad.) They are a little hard to come by.

Ways you can earn Toad Rally Tickets:

- Bonus Game - 1 every 8 hrs, if you are lucky.
- Collecting all pink/purple/black coins in a level - 2 per type of coin
- Completing a world - 10
- Buying them from My Nintendo (if you have a Nintendo Account linked)
- Leveling up - 2

So as you can see, when you buy the game, you will get a LOT more rally tickets to play with.

On the mission points part - you can spend mission points to get Toad Rally tickets and other items. You can get 10 rally tickets for 250 points there, however, you will have to do a LOT to get there so its really not beneficial to do that. However, there isn't really anything to save up for. You can chose what you want, however, the gold mario statue sounds really hard to get, so you could go for that.

Comment: This was a good answer about the rally ticket part of my question. The real question was about the "mission points" you earn. Would you update your response to reflect that part (if you know it), please?

Comment: @Grohlier Give me a minute, going to update it now. Do you have a Nintendo Account linked by the way?

Comment: I do. I actually have all characters unlocked other than Mrs Toad.

Comment: Well then there. Updated answer.

Comment: Lol, I don't know how to explain my question better. sorry. The original question is  - "What are mission points good for?" There are finite things to spend them on. Should I save them in case something special comes. Are they more or less pointless?

Comment: They are kind of pointless, but you can spend them on coins, toad rally tickets, others decorations like a gold mario statue.

Comment: @Grohlier I added more, if you want to look.